# Is there a way to restore uncommitted changes from a project when all I have is the .git folder?

Tags: git, github

After some mistakes, all I have left is a .git folder (and none of the files). When I do git status, a bunch of the uncommitted files I added before my unfortunate mistake show up  under "changes to be committed".

I tried "git reset --hard HEAD", but the uncommitted new files don't get restored and I'm wondering if there's a way to get the uncommitted changes I had before.

Edit: I did manage to make a copy of that .git folder before trying "git reset --hard HEAD" so hopefully there's still a possibility?

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD` will blow away **all** uncommitted changes, no way to recover.

Comment: If you used `git add`, this created *blob objects* in the repository for each added file. These are recoverable (though not terribly easily). If you saved the `.git` contents, though, you're in much more luck: Git's index is actually just the file `.git/index` (mostly anyway) so if you have the saved copy, you have everything you need to make a new commit from those blob objects. That commit will allow you to access the files easily.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two scenarios.

1. Your updated code is on the remote repository(already pushed on upstream).
   What you can do in this case is just checkout everything and take a pull of that branch again and you can get your commits back.

```
git checkout .
git pull
```

2. You are doing everything on your local. Which means you are not yet pushed your commits on remote.

First of all git reset --hard HEAD command resets your last commit and also checkout the files. So you have to again make changes to the code on your own because they are gone after reset --hard and cannot be retrieved.